# Реализовать GUI на PyQt5

Tags: gui, python-3.5, pyqt5

Нужно написать GUI приложение c графическими примитивами для создания и редактирования графа (узлы, ребра) на плоскости с использованием PyQt5 (Py3.5 + PyQt5 5.8.x).

С чего начать новичку в Python/PyQt, если опыт написания на Qt большой?

Есть ли книги по Python/PyQt, где уже рассматривается что-то похожее? Посоветуйте туториалы, в которых есть что-то по этой теме.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Я бы посоветовал просмотреть библитеку примеров, которая есть в Creator. Там точно есть примеры с интерактивной графической сценой.

Comment: Смотрите в сторону QGraphicsScene. В PyQt4/5 и PySide абсолютно тоже самое что в аналогичной версии Qt, там вообще сам Qt используется -- в тех модулях можно найти qt'шные dll

Comment: Спасибо, действительно есть примеры с QGraphicsScene в библиотеке примеров Qt Creator. Нет ли подобной библиотеки примеров для PyQt5? В чем разница между PyQt5 и PySide? Только в лицензии? Как происходит привязка Qt в PyQt5 и PySide: статически или динамически?